# spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize not being honored in a spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
```

whenever the JWT token in my request header is very lengthy

As a solution i tried adding the below to my properties file, but it did not solve my problem.

```
# Max file size.
spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize=100Mb
# Max request size.
spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize=100Mb
```

These are my dependencies in my build.gradle

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.1.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
compile 'org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:2.4.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.7.0'
compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0'
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.22.2'
compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.0'
compile group: 'com.lmax', name: 'disruptor', version: '3.2.0'
compile group: 'com.ibm.db2.jcc', name: 'jdbc-driver', version: '3.66.46'
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20140107'
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-test', version: '2.4.0.RELEASE'
```

Not really sure if my library versions are not right. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

posting the answer to the question myself, if it helps someone tomorrow.
Adding this to the application.properties file worked

```
server.tomcat.max-http-header-size=10240
```